# How to create dropdown list with inside search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Have Question That How can make a dropdown list Like this picture with the search in side the dropdown 
tnx for help 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw2de.png

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: If you make clear to the reader what question you are asking that will improve your chances of getting a useful reply.  Reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might give you some ideas.  It also improves your chances of getting a useful reply if you show the code you have tried so far and explain how that code fails.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some advice on how best to show your code

Answer (score 3):

Try **[Select-2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)** the best and simple way.

Includes :

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Example code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});

<select class="js-example-basic-single">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: Please Look at the Picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/jw2de.png then find out whats my means !!! there is <select><option> between this there is a input that type="text" !! how can i create it ?

Comment: I don't know if you're a web development newbie, anyway i recommended to take a real look at `select-2` examples, you can create your select with options like usual and the magic come in this line  `$("your_select").select2();` that will create a working `input` for you that filter/search automatically in your options, good luck.

Comment: i run your code ! but it take me ye select with 2option ! nothing more !

Comment: It's not my code it's from the source **[Select-2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)** and it should work 1000%.

Comment: i found the problem ! if the code wants to running you should load the bootstrap :| if didnt do that didnt work